# Automate a GUI Windows application with user inputs to run every week

Tags: c#, user-interface, automation

I have a simple Windows application which has two text boxes and one button called "Run". Currently, I have to manually enter the values in text boxes and click on Run button every week.  I want to automate this process, so that no user interaction should be required. Can I write a script to do this?

Comment: Assuming you don't have the source, [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) can help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have the source of your Windows application as you've tagged your question with C#. If so, then it's fairly straightforward to pass your text box values on the command line via something like Windows [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler), parse the command line parameters in your application, and pass them on to whatever you call when Run is pressed.

Comment: As you now say you dont have the source, David B's idea of using something like AutoHotKey sounds like a good bet.

Comment: Sorry i did not mention that i dont have the source code and this application was developed by someone else and my client gave me only the executable and i need to run this executable every week. I want to automate this process... Any idea?

Comment: No problem - i still think AutoHotKey or similar is a good bet. Its free, and you should be able to run AutoHotKey via Windows Scheduler to repeat the parameter injections each week (correct me if i'm wrong David?)

Answer (score 0):

Kicking it off at every X interval is one thing. I would suggest the Windows [Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler). However, it sounds like you need to interact with the GUI application after it's been launched. For that, all I can do is point you in the right direction. The only thing that comes to mind is to use a third-party GUI testing suite. Check out [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools). You can script any of these suites to interact with the GUI, that is, input some data and click on the `Run` button.

Comment: Don't you mean the Windows *[Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)* (not Task Manager)?